# If $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ are subspaces of $V$, both with orthonormal basis, then $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$, $W^{\perp}$ it's orthogonal complement in $V$, and say that both have orthonormal basis, and that $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space, then $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$.

I can see that $W \cap W^{\perp} = \{0\}$ but can someone show me why $\mathrm{span}\{W,W^{\perp}\}=V$?

Thanks

Comment: Choose an orthonormal basis for $W$ and extend it to an orthonormal basis for $V$. Then any basis element not in $W$ is normal to $W$, so lies in $W^{\perp}$.

Comment: How do you know you can extend an orthnormal basis of $W$ to an orthonormal basis for $V$?

Comment: You mean $\operatorname{span}(W \cup W^\perp) = V$ instead of $\operatorname{span}(\{W,W^\perp\}) = V$?

Comment: Extend it to any basis and then apply Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: What is $V$?  You did not say $V$ is complete, you did not say $V$ is separable.  Because you wrote $W^\perp$, I assume $V$ is an inner product space.  But in general an inner product space need not have an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: @Eugene: every finite-dimensional inner product space has an orthonormal basis so you don't need that as an additional hypothesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $v\in V$. If $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $W$, then

$$w=\langle v,w_1\rangle w_1+\langle v,w_2\rangle w_2+ \dots + \langle v,w_n\rangle w_n\in W.$$

And $v-w$ is orthogonal to each $w_k$ and therefore $v-w\in W^\perp$. So,$$v=w+(v-w)\in\operatorname{span}\{W,W^\perp\}.$$

Comment: Note that this argument actually shows that we don't need to assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional, only that $W$ is (so that the projection to $W$ can be computed using an orthonormal basis of it).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that's a nice remark.

Comment: Can somebody help me to see that $v-w$ is orthogonal to each $w_k$?

Comment: It's because$$\langle v-w,w_k\rangle=\langle v,w_k\rangle-\langle w,w_k\rangle=\langle v,w_k\rangle-\langle v,w_k\rangle=0.$$